# Saving my Geocube object as a raster is way too big

Tags: python, rasterization, geocube

I am rasterizing some polygon data with make_geocube and exporting the result as a .tif file. It works, but my file sizes are orders of magnitude larger (10-20x) what I am expecting them to be after making similar files in ArcGIS Pro. For instance, I am feeding a polygon file that is less than 1 GB, and the resulting TIFF is 17GB. I have taken some steps to reduce the data size as much as possible (int34), but the output file size is still way too large. I have done this work in the ArcGIS Pro environment for input files around 3.25GB and get outs puts of .4 GB.

This is my code as it is right now:

```
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
from geocube.rasterize import rasterize_image

def polygonsToRaster(poly):
    polygons = poly
    polygons = polygons.to_crs('EPSG:4326')
    
    # Using GeoCube to rasterize the Vector
    raster = make_geocube(
        vector_data = polygons,
        measurements=["Value"],
        resolution=(-9.96023190602395e-05, 9.96023190602395e-05),
        fill = -99999
    )
    return raster

geocube_object = polygonsToRaster(polygon_file)

geocube_object["Value"] = geocube_object.Value.astype('int32')

geocube_object.rio.to_raster('output.tif')
```

Why is this output.tif file so large, and is there something I can do to create the TIFF smaller?

Comment: With uncompressed TIFF you can count the file size beforehand: it is the width x height x band count x bit depth, where width and height are in pixels and bit depth in bytes. 10000 by 10000 pixels sized 8-bit RGB image is 300 MB (+ a few bytes for image headers). The file size of the source vector file does not play any role. The geographical extent of the vector data together with the pixel size does play role.
For making the file size of the raster smaller you have two options: create bigger pixels, or create a compressed TIFF. LZW and Deflate compressions are lossless.

Comment: "int34" isn't a thing in raster formats.  int32 yes, int16 sure, int64 sometimes, but not int34.